# Angular 1.x and AG-Grid Components

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to upgrade our app from a really old version to the latest (v16).   Since they have deprecated the old way of cell and header renders I'm trying to wrap my head around using scope and Angular compilation.

> The ag-grid documentation states:  You will then need to manage creating and destroying child scopes yourself inside the init() and destroy() methods. 
>    angularCompileRows, angularCompileFilters and angularCompileHeaders are not supported within Components.

I tried to create a cell render like this:

```
  function MyCellRenderer() {
  }

  MyCellRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
      $scope.myMessage = 'Hi Scott';
      var compiled = $compile('<p ng-bind="myMessage"></p>')($scope);
      this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
      this.eGui.innerHTML = compiled.html();
  };

  MyCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function () {
      return this.eGui;
  };
```

However this doesn't work.   Any thoughts?

I was able to get this to work, but I don't like that I need to wrap around a $timeout.  I had to do this because a digest was already in progress:

```
  function MyCellRendererSimple() {
  }

  MyCellRendererSimple.prototype.init = function (params) {
    console.log('init Called');
      this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
  };

  MyCellRendererSimple.prototype.getGui = function () {
      var self = this;

      $timeout(function() {
        var compiled = $compile('<nice-checkbox  checkbox-id="checkbox-2" ng-model="checkboxModal1"></nice-checkbox>')($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        self.eGui.appendChild(compiled[0]);
      });

      return self.eGui;
  };
```

Comment: I added a a $scope.$digest() after the $compile but that didn't help.

Comment: compiled.html() << this is string. You discard result of $compile when run it. Use $element#append. Also notice that you are not creating new child scope. (not sure if u want to)